# Relating one model to multiple models based on field

Tags: database, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, non-relational-database

Here's a brief description of the models:

- Model A represents a piece of equipment and has a name and a state
- Model B represents a specific state of many model A's
- Model B should relate to many model A's but only for a specific state of model A

Is it possible to model something like this in the datastore? I need the state of model A to be independent of any model B's, but when I peer into a model B I need to know what the state of the model A's should be that the model B is representing.

The current way I am achieving this is by making model B have string fields representing the different model A's with the name of the field being the name of the model A and the value of the field being the state the model A is supposed to be in.

This works, however it's completely static and requires manually adding fields into model B when the number of model A's change. I'm looking for a dynamic approach to solve this problem.

I hope this isn't too confusing, please ask for more clarification if it's needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reference properties for this:

```
class A(db.Model):
    state = db.ReferenceProperty(collection_name="equipment")
```

When you create A, you set the `state` property to the corresponding `B` entity.

This also creates a property in the `B` entity called `equipment` that can be used to get all the `A` entities that reference the particular `B`.

Suppose you have a `B` entity for broken equipment in a variable `broken`.  You can get all the broken equipment this way

```
broken.equipment.get()
```

This is also available with `ndb` but the details are a little different and you'll need to check the docs for that.